# "docker: 'compose' is not a docker command" when running docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After installing the latest version of Docker Desktop on my M1 Mac pro, I can't seem to run docker compose despite having all the correct files installed.

I've tried running `docker-compose` and `docker compose` in my terminal and I get this message: `docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.`

After running `docker --version`, I'm currently on `Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f`

Compose is correctly added to my PATH vars under `/usr/local/bin/`, which has the following files:

```
com.docker.cli          docker-credential-desktop       fuzzy_match         kubectl.docker
docker                  docker-credential-ecr-login     httpclient          vpnkit
docker-compose          docker-credential-osxkeychain   hub-tool            xcodeproj
docker-compose-v1       docker-index                    kubectl
```

When I run `which docker-compose`, it returns `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` so it seems like everything is configured correctly.

Also running `docker-compose-v1` does seem to work for some weird reason.

Any ideas?

Edit: Seems like this was fixed after installing the newest version of Docker (Docker Desktop 4.14.1 (91661), Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f).

Comment: Can u check, that in your have under Docker Desktop > Settings > General > "Use Docker Compose V2" enabled?

Comment: I'd just go ahead and use `docker-compose` with the hyphen, if it works.

Comment: @tjarbo Yes it is enabled.

Comment: @DavidMaze It doesn't work. I tried both `docker compose` and `docker-compose`

Comment: For people who use centos7, `docker-compose-plugin-2.12.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm` will install `docker-compose` at `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install Rosetta 2 with `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`, then uncheck *Use Docker Compose V2* in Docker Dashboard -> Settings -> General.

Comment: It worked! Now I can run `docker-compose` but can't run the alias `docker compose`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: As you probably already know, `docker compose` is the command to summon the new Go-based Docker Compose V2. I assume that there is some sort of temporary issue with version Docker Desktop 4.14.0 (91374) on Apple M1 (I had the same problem as you.) The quickest solution I could find was to temporarily revert back to V1, which requires Rosetta. I was able to run V2 on my M1 perfectly fine, up until a few days ago, so I hope the Docker dev wizards fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue because I had not yet set up docker desktop. After opening the Docker Desktop app and allowing it to complete the install process, `docker-compose` worked as expected.